# Why php can work in 127.0.0.1 but not localhost

Tags: php

Why php can work in `127.0.0.1` but not `localhost`

It made me confused

My OS is windows 10

Comment: We would need to know a little more about your setup to answer. However it could be one of two things either your hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) doesn't contain a localhost entry, which is very unlikely, or localhost is not a recognised host for your webserver.

Comment: This question is off topic without having enough details

Comment: probably because your vhost isn't set up correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should point your localhost domain name to 127.0.0.1

Open your Notepad as Administrator, then open file `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` and append below line EOF.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

then save the file, it should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a windows issue and not a PHP issue. Your hosts file for windows is not correctly configured to map the name localhost to the 127.0.0.1 IP address. Generally its safer to just use the IP anyway since its less likely that this will ever be identified incorrectly.

If you need to make localhost work, use this guide to find and open the file https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/

You then need to add `127.0.0.1 localhost` to the file and localhost will then work